# localnotification with various alert message

Tags: iphone, uialertview, uilocalnotification

I want to fire local notification multiple time.and every time notification alert message should be different,below there are tow mothod and delegate method didreceivelocalnotification. this is giving same alert msg all the time but i want to display different alert for different local notification .

method one

```
{

UILocalNotification *local =[ [UILocalNotification alloc]init];

local.fireDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];

local.fireDate = start_fire_date;
```

}

method 2

```
{

UILocalNotification *local =[ [UILocalNotification alloc]init];

local.fireDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];

local.fireDate = end_fire_date;
```

}

```
application idReceiveLocalNotification:UILocalNotification {alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You come back ! (app was closed)" message:customInfo delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set message when u fire notification..

```
localNotif.alertBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"message"];
```

Answer (score 0):

From local notification .h file

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *soundName;      // name of resource in app's bundle to play or UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
```

Set this to a sound file in your bundle

Example

```
UILocalNotification *local =[ [UILocalNotification alloc]init];

local.fireDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
local.soundName = @"yourSoundFile";
local.fireDate = end_fire_date;
```